# Хеширование нескольких string сразу

Tags: c#, строки, хеширование

```
static string str = "abcdefghijklmnoparstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPaRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ac = Console.ReadLine();
        for (int a = 0; (a < str.Length); a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; (b < str.Length); b++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; (c < str.Length); c++)
                {
                    for (int d = 0; d < 3; d++)
                    {
                        for (int d1 = 3; d1 < 6; d1++)
                        {
                            string s111 = str[a].ToString() + str[b].ToString() + str[c].ToString() + str[d].ToString();
                            string s112 = str[a].ToString() + str[b].ToString() + str[c].ToString() + str[d1].ToString();
                            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
                            Byte[] bytes4MD5 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s111);
                            byte[] checkSum = md5.ComputeHash(bytes4MD5);
                            string result = BitConverter.ToString(checkSum).Replace("-", String.Empty);
                            if (result.ToLower().StartsWith(ac))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(s111 + ":" + result.ToLower());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

У меня есть такой код, и есть только одна проблема: как мне добиться того, чтобы хешировалась не только строка *s111*, но и также строка *s112*?

P.S. Пробовал `Byte[] bytes4MD5 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s111, s112);` но железка такой записи не понимает.

Comment: НЕ совсем понятно, что вы хотите?

Comment: Почему склеить и получить хэш от получившейся строки

Comment: @AlexsandrTer чтобы софт хешировал с начало строку s111 а также s112

Comment: @AlexsandrTer я только что попробовал сделать так что мол (s111+s112), и комп сразу понял..

Comment: или же это и есть ответ на мой вопрос ?

Comment: @May_be вам лучше знать, отвечает ли это на ваш вопрос.

Comment: нет, ошибся не много

Comment: @D-side и все таки как мне сделать "ComputeHash() считает хэш и финализирует его. Повторно его использовать не выйдет. Чтобы хэшировать несколько блоков данных, нужно вызывать TransformBlock(), который добавляет данные в контекст хэша и в конце - TransformFinalBlock(), который хэш финализует и выдает результат"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ComputeHash()` считает хэш и финализирует его. Повторно его использовать не выйдет. Чтобы хэшировать несколько блоков данных, нужно вызывать `TransformBlock()`, который добавляет данные в контекст хэша и в конце - `TransformFinalBlock()`, который хэш финализует и выдает результат

Comment: так как тогда должно быть ?

Comment: @May_be в MSDN есть примеры. Копипастить их не вижу смысла.

Comment: ссылку дайте пж, там есть примеры как сделать хеш от энтое кол-ство строк ?

Comment: @May_be https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformfinalblock(v=vs.110).aspx вот пример хэширования нескольких блоков с последующей финализацией.

Comment: все равно не понимаю как написать, вы можете редактировать код мне ?

Comment: @May_be может и могу, но не лучше ли вам самому научиться?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42907/discussion-between-may-be-and--).

Comment: Мне лучше если мне напишут чем если я сам буду тратить уйму времени

Comment: @May_be: вам нужно потратить некоторое время для того, чтобы получить базовый навык взаимодействия с www.google.com и MSDN. Без этого вы не сможете продвинуться дальше в изучении программирования как такового.